# Move file or directory to C:\\Windows using PHP - XAMPP

Tags: php, xampp

I am stuck in a script. I am developing a php based application and client can use it offline using XAMPP server after installation. I want to create a file called lic.txt during installation and i have managed to create it as well..

The only problem i am facing is i am unable to move the file into **C:\Windows** Folder and i want to move it there only. I am able to move file anywhere within XAMPP folder which is installed at **C:\XAMPP**

Code is something like this :

```
  <?php
    $filename = 'lic.txt';
$data = 'License Registered Successfully';
$newlocation = 'C:\\Windows\\lic.txt';
    $fh = fopen($filename, 'w'); 
     fwrite($fh, $data); 
     fclose($fh);
    rename($filename, $newlocation);

    ?>
```

When i run the file it is giving me the error

```
Warning: rename(lic.txt,C:\Windows\lic.txt): Access is denied. (code: 5) in C:\xampp\htdocs\latest\fwrite.php on line 9
```

I know this is because insufficient privileges to the folder but i have searched the whole web but couldn't find any solution. Is there anyone who can help me out to resolve the issue.

Thanks...

Answer (score 0):

To begin with, that is not the kind of application PHP is designed for. There are much better choices.

In order to read or write to the windows directory, you need to run XMAPP with administrator privileges. Which will probably make it difficult to deploy this to any customer.

Comment: Then how can i achieve what is needed? You are saying it is not possible??

Comment: You need to run Apache with administrator level permissions. This is not necessarily a good idea since it can open the compute up to security issues. Nor do all users have privileges to run at this level anyway.

Comment: can i expect a positive reply?

Comment: @ShreyaPorwal the problem is that the user who runs httpd.exe doesn't have permissions to write on `C:\Windows` (which is really good!) Try to change your destination path to: `C:\xampp\htdocs` and let me know. This is just a permssion issue. Believe me you don't want to change permission for `C:\Windows`